# How do I set the fields in the facebook registration plugin?

Tags: php, facebook, plugins, registration

I have the facebook registration plugin on the site and I'm correctly parsing the signed request from facebook. However, I want to set the fields with the data I've just received when the page reloads so all the fields are not blank. How do I access these fields to set them? From reading the documentation, I noticed that there is a variable called 'form' that gets passed to a function if the onvalidate field is specified in the facebook registration plugin.

However, this is only effective on submit, not on page load so I can't really use that. Is there any other method of setting the registration fields?

Comment: Um, is this a stupid question or something?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the PHP array function to request what you want pulled out of the info that gets sent. For example

if you want the users email it would be

```
$email = $response["registration"]["email"];
```

If you want custom fields then you'll need to read the documentation and add the custom fields into the &fields section of the registraton page. Don't forget to define them in your callback url though!

P.S if you can answer my question now that'd be great ;) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405647/facebook-registration-connect)

-Brad